# Catching the message before InsertControl procedure

Tags: performance, delphi

I try to create huge number of TWinControl (100 000) at runtime. It goes quickly. But if I change the type to TCustomControl (which has useful property Canvas), it goes pretty slow. The reason for it is, that constructor of TCustomControl creates TControlCanvas too, and it slows down the process significantly. 
My idea is to make a descendant of TWinControl, which would create TControlCanvas only, when it is inserted on the form. (This huge number is not inserted implicitly)

Is it possible to catch event before (or right after) the descendant is inserted?

Thanx for ideas

Comment: Would make much more sense to lazy create the `TCustomControl` objects.

Comment: I'm sure you will be asked for more information on this.  My first reaction is creating 100,000 controls is a really bad idea.  There is not even any way to show that many controls on the screen so why do you need them created?

Comment: @Mark Elder: This is only experimental stage. I just focus on the performance. The controls can paint themselves on the another canvas (let say TScrollbox, TPaintBox... ), so they can be positioned virtually, without need of being parented. And it is fast. Controls display data from TDataset, that's why I expect great numbers of rows - controls to be displayed.

Comment: Your design is awful. Quite dreadful. What makes you think you need one control per row in the data set? Really, find a sensible approach.

Comment: @David Heffernan: :-) thanx... it is more complicated. I want to use these components (and any other components) to design table row. (like a prototype). Then this table row clone itself after connecting to db table. In the end it should be far more flexible aproach then to use TDBGrid - the data could be displayed beyond TDBgrid capabilities (left to right display, multi line, real components inside when necessary and many many more...)

Comment: You never need 100,000 visual components. Ever.

Comment: @David Heffernan: you're maybe right... but I hope this is not the only answer to my question... ;-)

Comment: Why would you hope that? Wouldn't you want to do it the right way? Or do you enjoy pain?!  ;-)

Comment: @lyborko: The VCL seem to send `CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGE` (before insert) and `CM_CONTROLCHANGE` (after insert) messages to the container. You might want to check them.

Comment: If you won't need its handle before inserting the control, a WinControl will acquire its handle when you intend to set a parent to it. So you can override 'CreateWnd' for instance. On another note, your design with that many windows may put significant burden on the OS.